# how can i bookmark given line numbers in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

Suppose I have a list of 1000 entries. I can bookmark a line by clicking on the left right before the first character of that line. The blue dot marks the line.

I have a file with a list of numbers. These are line numbers that need to be bookmarked in notepad++.

```
1
2
3
6
13
14
21
26
60
```

Can I bookmark these line numbers all at once in notepad++ or do I need to click one at a time? Manual marking will take a long time since the list is long. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But you could write a simple script in your favorite scripting language. What are you tring to achieve?

Comment: Now the question boils down to "is there any recommendation for a plugin that supports scripting in Notepad++ and how do I write that program?" which is obviously off-topic.

Comment: ok if that is not possible i found a workaround. i can read the list and append a symbol that is not in the file like *. Then i can mark all lines with * in notepad ++. Ok i think i ll resort to this if there is no direct way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this same thing today to check text config files for specific values.  What I came up with is to record a macro

Macro

 
--Start Recording
---Search
----GoTo [ctrl]+[g]
----Line #
----[ctrl]+[F2] *book marks line
----Goto
----.
----.
---Stop Recording